# Python dataframe use apply function with multiple lambda

Tags: python, pandas, progress-bar

I have a short script. I use that script for for example I have dataset
I try to group by id first 3 then I try to group them again but this time I try to merge name, url and house
example output and input
data set

input csv

```
id,name,house 
1,a,house1,
1,aa,house2
1,aaa,house3
2,b,house4
2,bb,house5
2,bbb,house6
3,c,house7
3,cc,house8
3,ccc,house9
4,d,house10
4,dd,house11
4,ddd,house12
4,dddd, house13
```

the output csv

```
1,a,house1,aa,house2,aaa,houes3
2,b,house4,bb,house5,bbb,houes6
3,c,house7,cc,house8,ccc,houes9
4,d,house10,dd,house11,ddd,house12
```

script

```
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
    df.sort_values(by=['id'])
    df = df.groupby('id').head(3).groupby('id').agg({
        'name': lambda l: ','.join(l),
        'house': lambda l: ','.join(l)
    })
    df[['name_first', 'name_second', 'name_third']] = df.name.str.split(',', expand=True)
    df[['house_first', 'house_second', 'house_third']] = df.house.str.split(',', expand=True)

    df = df.reset_index().drop(['name', 'house'], axis=1)
    df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

I want to add progressbar, but I couldn't add, If I can switch agg func to apply func, I think I will be able to switch it `progress_apply` but I couldn't change how can I do that, I need progressbar because I have really huge csv file which over 10 millions lines so it is gonna take time, I want to track process

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you please make it clearer what is your goal, is it to build a progress bar?

Comment: I tried to explain more clearer I hope its fine

Comment: give sample CSV input datasets and expected csv output dataset. and also the logic of your merging function. i can make a progress bar for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '4'],
 'name': ['a',  'aa',  'aaa',  'b',  'bb',  'bbb',  'c',  'cc',  'ccc',  'd',  'dd',  'ddd',  'dddd'], 
 'house': ['house1',  'house2',  'house3',  'house4',  'house5', 'house6',  'house7',  'house8',  'house9',  'house10',  'house11',  'house12',  ' house13']
})
```

This approach creates a pivot table

```
outcome = df.groupby('id').head(3)\
    .assign(count=df.groupby('id').cumcount())\
    .set_index(['id', 'count']).unstack()\
    .sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
```

and then we can save it after renaming the columns

```
outcome.columns = [f'{x}_{str(y)}' for x, y in outcome.columns]
outcome.to_csv('...')
```

But this does not come with a progress bar because I did not use `apply`.

To use progress bar for the sake of using it:

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

outcome = df.groupby('id').progress_apply(
    lambda x: x.head(3).reset_index(drop=True).set_index('id', append=True).unstack(0),
).droplevel(0).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)

outcome.columns = [f'{x}_{str(y)}' for x, y in outcome.columns]
outcome.to_csv('...')
```

Please try the both approaches and see which is faster.